# Vs-Code: Replace uppercase letter in words except first one with lowercase ones

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Using Vs Code I would like to replace every 2nd uppercase letter in a word to the matching lowercase one only if the first 2 letters of the word are uppercase.

Example: `LEtter` would become `Letter`, but `iOS`, `US` or `DNA` would remain unchanged.

I figured using regular expressions and use the replace feature: the appropriate search string to use could be `\s[A-Z][A-Z][a-z]` (but probably this one doesn't work if I want to use it to replace stuff?). However, I don't know how to replace the 2nd letter then.

I am grateful for suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression Find/Replace with **Match Case** (`Aa` button)

Find: `\b([A-Z])([A-Z])([a-z]+)\b`

Replace: `$1\l$2$3`

In front of the `$2` is a lowercase L

Group each part and convert the second capture group to lower case.